# pandas; concatenate any groups that share members

Tags: python, pandas

Consider a dataframe that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
my_df = pd.DataFrame({'column_1':[['a'], ['b', 'c', 'd'], ['e', 'f'], ['g'], ['h', 'i'], ['j']], 
'column_2':[['a', 'b'], ['c'], ['d'], ['e', 'f', 'g'], ['h', 'i'], ['j']]})
my_df

>>> my_df

  column_1   column_2
0        [a]     [a, b]
1  [b, c, d]        [c]
2     [e, f]        [d]
3        [g]  [e, f, g]
4     [h, i]     [h, i]
5        [j]        [j]
```

Now, column 1 has value a at index 0, and value b at index 1. In column_2, a and b are both in index 0. I'd like to essentially create 'supergroups' that collect all the groups that link together, however far that linkage is. So, I'd have a group `[a, b, c, d]`, `[e, f, g]`, `[h, i]`, and `[j]`.

I've had some thoughts on the matter, but I can't quite clinch a solution without a ridiculous for-loop that won't scale.

Firstly, I do have a list of all the values that appear in either column, IE, `my_values=[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j]`. I can set something up like this:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'vals':sorted(list(my_values))})
new_df['col_1'] = new_df.vals.apply(lambda x: my_df.loc[my_df.column_1.apply(lambda y: x in y)].index.values[0]) 

new_df['col_2'] = new_df.vals.apply(lambda x: my_df.loc[my_df.column_2.apply(lambda y: x in y)].index.values[0]) 

new_df

  vals  col_1  col_2
0    a      0      0
1    b      1      0
2    c      1      1
3    d      1      2
4    e      2      3
5    f      2      3
6    g      3      3
7    h      4      4
8    i      4      4
9    j      5      5
```

I thought making the indices of where these values occur programmatically accessible would help create a solution. However, a) getting this indices doesn't look like something that would scale well the way I've written it, and b) I don't know where to go from here. I tried to do a mix-match of groupby and agg commands, but only ended up redefining my problem, without solving it. I think I'm probably approaching this the wrong way. How would you advise I proceed?

**EDIT** 
To help clear up what I'm trying to do:

`a` is at `index 0` in `column 1` and `column 2`. As such, any other values at `index 0` belong to `group 0`. `b` is at `index 0`, and so belongs to `group 0`. `b` occurs at `index 1` in `column 1`; as such, any values in `column 1`, `index 1` will belong to `group 0` as well. This includes `c` and `d`. This further extends the chain: `c` occurs at `index 1` in `column 2`, and `d` occurs at `index 3` in `column 2`. Since these are the only 2 values in their respective groups, the chain is not extended.

In this way, `a, b, c, and d` wind up in `group 0`. A similar logic needs to be applied going through these two columns to create 'super groups' for all of our values, where you cannot find any value in the 'super group' that links to another value in one of the regular column groups without that other value also being in the 'super group'.

Comment: it is not clear how you define a group, can you elaborate?

Comment: What do you mean when you say you want to "collect all the groups that link together"? Are these all of the letters in each row?

Comment: I've edited to include more details.

Comment: This looks a lot like a [set consolidation](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Set_consolidation) with each entry in your dataframe being a set to be merged. Using an off-the-shelf consolidation function gives me `consolidate([set(x) for x in my_df.values.flat]) == [{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'}, {'e', 'f', 'g'}, {'h', 'i'}, {'j'}]`.

Comment: this sounds like a graph problem but your description is too confusing, looks like from a you can reach `a` and `b`, from [`b`, `c` and `d`] you can only go to `c` so effectively group 0 is all the points reachable from `a`, correct?

Comment: @DSM: That looks perfect. I'm going to need to test it at scale to see if it works, but I honestly can't imagine a solution being much better.

Comment: this is a disjoint-sets problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure

Answer (score 1):

Base on what you mentioned above : Notice `explode` is new in pandas 0.25.0

```
pd.concat([df[x].explode().reset_index().set_index(x)['index'] for x in list(df)],keys=np.arange(df.shape[1])+1,axis = 1)
Out[211]: 
   1  2
a  0  0
b  1  0
c  1  1
d  1  2
e  2  3
f  2  3
g  3  3
h  4  4
i  4  4
j  5  5
```

Comment: I hadn't realized explode got added to pandas; it's definitely a handy tool, but it doesn't quite answer the question here.